# No data in the PurchaserInfo object

Tags: flutter, revenuecat

Here are my logs when after initilizing I print(purchaserInfo.toString())

I think this might be why I am unable to see any products when I try to display them

```
D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(12538): Debug logging enabled.
D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(12538): SDK Version - 3.2.0
D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(12538): Initial App User ID - null
D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(12538): Identifying App User ID: aswq4Sdfaewradfgasfw
D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(12538): Deleting old synced subscriber attributes that don't belong to aswq4Sdfaewradfgasfw.
D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(12538): App foregrounded
D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(12538): PurchaserInfo cache is stale, updating caches
D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(12538): Offerings cache is stale, updating caches
D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(12538): [QueryPurchases] Skipping updating pending purchase queue since BillingClient is not connected yet
D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(12538): No subscriber attributes to synchronize.
D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(12538): Listener set
D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(12538): Sending latest purchaser info to listener
D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(12538): Starting connection for com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClientImpl@f8168e4
D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(12538): Vending purchaserInfo from cache
D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(12538): Vending purchaserInfo from cache
D/NetworkSecurityConfig(12538): No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(12538): Billing Service Setup finished for com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClientImpl@f8168e4.
D/[Purchases] - DEBUG(12538): [QueryPurchases] Updating pending purchase queue
I/flutter (12538): PurchaserInfo{entitlements: EntitlementInfos{all: {}, active: {}}, latestExpirationDate: null, allExpirationDates: {}, allPurchaseDates: {}, activeSubscriptions: [], allPurchasedProductIdentifiers: [], firstSeen: 2020-07-06T03:12:21.000Z, originalAppUserId: aswq4Sdfaewradfgasfw, requestDate: 2020-07-07T00:29:14.000Z, originalApplicationVersion: null, originalPurchaseDate: null, managementURL: null}
```

This is running on Android using:   purchases_flutter: ^1.1.1

Comment: Did you follow all steps mentioned here https://docs.revenuecat.com/docs/flutter

Comment: Yes as well as integrating it with iOS app connect. I believe if it was an issue with that there would be a different error?

Comment: The `PurchaserInfo` object contains data about the user's purchases and current level of access. It's expected to be empty until a user makes a purchase.